# Multiple products in listener, paypal IPN

Tags: php, post, paypal, paypal-ipn

im using paypal IPN to send information to my php code that will take that info and send attachment product to buyers email.

My question is if i can have multiple products in one listener, or i need separate file for every product?

What if 2 or more clients buy product at the same time, can there be any problem? 
Like sending attachment only to one of them instead of two or more.

```html
<?php
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
 require "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
 require "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
 }

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cmd=_notify-validate&" . http_build_query($_POST));
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 if ($response == "VERIFIED" && $_POST['receiver_email'] == "your-email@hotmail.com") {
  $cEmail = $_POST['payer_email'];
  $name = $_POST['first_name'] . " " . $_POST['last_name'];

  $price = $_POST['mc_gross'];
  $currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
  $item = $_POST['item_number'];
  $paymentStatus = $_POST['payment_status'];

  if ($item == "wordpressPlugin" && $currency == "USD" && $paymentStatus == "Completed" && $price == 67) {
   $mail = new PHPMailer();

   $mail->setFrom("your-email@hotmail.com", "Sales");
   $mail->addAttachment("attachment/wordpress-plugin.zip", "WordPress Plugin");
   $mail->addAddress($cEmail, $name);
   $mail->isHTML(true);
   $mail->Subject = "Your Purchase Details";
   $mail->Body = "
    Hi, <br><br>
    Thank you for purchase. In the attachment you will 
                find product<br><br>
    
    Kind regards.
   ";

   $mail->send();
  }
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there would be no problems with that.  The IPN data will include an array of cart items, so you can loop through those and do whatever you need to do with each item.

You may be interested in our [IPN template](https://www.angelleye.com/project/paypal-ipn-php-template/).  It's a bit out-dated now, but you can [see how we're preparing $cart_items into an array](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template/blob/release/parse-ipn-data.php) that's easy to loop through.

```
// Cart Items
$num_cart_items = isset($_POST['num_cart_items']) ? $_POST['num_cart_items'] : '';

$i = 1;
$cart_items = array();   
while(isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]))   
{   
    $item_number = isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_number' . $i] : '';   
    $item_name = isset($_POST['item_name' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_name' . $i] : '';   
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity' . $i]) ? $_POST['quantity' . $i] : '';  
    $mc_gross = isset($_POST['mc_gross_' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_gross_' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_handling = isset($_POST['mc_handling' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_handling' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_shipping = isset($_POST['mc_shipping' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_shipping' . $i] : 0;
    $custom = isset($_POST['custom' . $i]) ? $_POST['custom' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name1 = isset($_POST['option_name1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection1 = isset($_POST['option_selection1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name2 = isset($_POST['option_name2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name2_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection2 = isset($_POST['option_selection2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection2_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name3 = isset($_POST['option_name3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name3_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection3 = isset($_POST['option_selection3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection3_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name4 = isset($_POST['option_name4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name4_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection4 = isset($_POST['option_selection4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection4_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name5 = isset($_POST['option_name5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name5_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection5 = isset($_POST['option_selection5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection5_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name6 = isset($_POST['option_name6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name6_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection6 = isset($_POST['option_selection6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection6_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name7 = isset($_POST['option_name7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name7_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection7 = isset($_POST['option_selection7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection7_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name8 = isset($_POST['option_name8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name8_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection8 = isset($_POST['option_selection8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection8_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name9 = isset($_POST['option_name9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name9_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection9 = isset($_POST['option_selection9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection9_' . $i] : '';

    $btn_id = isset($_POST['btn_id' . $i]) ? $_POST['btn_id' . $i] : '';

    $current_item = array(   
                           'item_number' => $item_number,   
                           'item_name' => $item_name,   
                           'quantity' => $quantity, 
                           'mc_gross' => $mc_gross, 
                           'mc_handling' => $mc_handling, 
                           'mc_shipping' => $mc_shipping, 
                           'custom' => $custom,   
                           'option_name1' => $option_name1,   
                           'option_selection1' => $option_selection1,   
                           'option_name2' => $option_name2,   
                           'option_selection2' => $option_selection2, 
                           'option_name3' => $option_name3, 
                           'option_selection3' => $option_selection3, 
                           'option_name4' => $option_name4, 
                           'option_selection4' => $option_selection4, 
                           'option_name5' => $option_name5, 
                           'option_selection5' => $option_selection5, 
                           'option_name6' => $option_name6, 
                           'option_selection6' => $option_selection6, 
                           'option_name7' => $option_name7, 
                           'option_selection7' => $option_selection7, 
                           'option_name8' => $option_name8, 
                           'option_selection8' => $option_selection8, 
                           'option_name9' => $option_name9, 
                           'option_selection9' => $option_selection9, 
                           'btn_id' => $btn_id
                          );   

    array_push($cart_items, $current_item);   
    $i++;   
}
```

And then...

```
// Loop through cart items and add each to related order_items table
foreach($cart_items as $cart_item)
{
    $cart_item_data['order_id'] = $order_id;
    $cart_item_data['subscr_id'] = $subscr_id;
    $cart_item_data['item_name'] = $cart_item['item_name'];
    $cart_item_data['item_number'] = $cart_item['item_number'];
    $cart_item_data['os0'] = $cart_item['option_selection1'];
    $cart_item_data['on0'] = $cart_item['option_name1'];
    $cart_item_data['os1'] = $cart_item['option_selection2'];
    $cart_item_data['on1'] = $cart_item['option_name2'];
    $cart_item_data['os2'] = $cart_item['option_selection3'];
    $cart_item_data['on2'] = $cart_item['option_name3'];
    $cart_item_data['os3'] = $cart_item['option_selection4'];
    $cart_item_data['on3'] = $cart_item['option_name4'];
    $cart_item_data['os4'] = $cart_item['option_selection5'];
    $cart_item_data['on4'] = $cart_item['option_name5'];
    $cart_item_data['os5'] = $cart_item['option_selection6'];
    $cart_item_data['on5'] = $cart_item['option_name6'];
    $cart_item_data['os6'] = $cart_item['option_selection7'];
    $cart_item_data['on6'] = $cart_item['option_name7'];
    $cart_item_data['os7'] = $cart_item['option_selection8'];
    $cart_item_data['on7'] = $cart_item['option_name8'];
    $cart_item_data['os8'] = $cart_item['option_selection9'];
    $cart_item_data['on8'] = $cart_item['option_name9'];
    $cart_item_data['quantity'] = $cart_item['quantity'];
    $cart_item_data['custom'] = $cart_item['custom'];
    $cart_item_data['mc_gross'] = $cart_item['mc_gross'];
    $cart_item_data['mc_handling'] = $cart_item['mc_handling'];
    $cart_item_data['mc_shipping'] = $cart_item['mc_shipping'];
    $cart_item_data['raw_log_id'] = $ipn_log_data_id;
    $cart_item_data['btn_id'] = $cart_item['btn_id'];

    $cart_item_id = $db -> query_insert('order_items', $cart_item_data);
}
```

That example prepares the data to enter in the db, but you should be able to apply that to whatever you're doing.